# I'm searching for the correct syntax to get-recipient -filter with multiple critera

Tags: powershell, filter

this script is to copy exchange online groups where names doesn't include acq,refi,entree) it works only for one critera:

```
> Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq '$dn' -and DisplayName -notlike  'acq.*'"




 Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq '$dn' -and DisplayName -notlike  'acq.* -or DisplayName -notlike  'refi.* -or DisplayName -notlike  'entree*'"
```

error message:

> Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on
> parameter 'Filter'. Cannot convert value "Members -eq
> 'CN=forname.name,OU=contoso.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft  Exchange
> Hosted Organizations,DC=EURPR04A007,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM' -and
> DisplayName -notlike 'acq.* -or DisplayName -notlike 'refi.* -or
> DisplayName -notlike 'entree*'" to type  "System.String". Error:
> "Invalid filter syntax. For a description of the filter parameter
> syntax see the command help. "Members -eq
> 'CN=forname.name,OU=contoso.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange
> Hosted Organizations,DC=EURPR04A007,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM' -and
> DisplayName -notlike 'acq.* -or  DisplayName -notlike 'refi.* -or
> DisplayName -notlike 'entree*'" at position 204." Au caractère
> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_h4hztqv3.n20\tmpEXO_h4hztqv3.n20.psm1:1162
> : 13

this syntax is not working I try lot of things without success so I am asking for some help

Comment: What happens? Does `Get-Recipient` throw an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: error message added